# Почему switch-case в php возвращает в locale index

Tags: php

не могу ни как понять, почему конструкция switch возвращает в locale index. Я хочу добавить текст в адресную строку блаузера, через конструкцию switch, а вместо того чтобы перейти по нужному адресу, конструкция возвращает в локальную страницу сайта.
*Это пример моего кода*:

```
$sistems = "sis";

switch ($sistems) {
case "1":
    echo "sistems";
    break;   }
<li>
<a class="btn-solid-reg 
popup-with-move-anim"
 href="?sis=1/menu- 
detail.php?id=<?php echo 
$data['Menu_ID'];?>">
 Читать подробне</a>
<li>
```

*Ссылка для примера, кликните по статье*
https://info.shihzamanapp.com/?link=sistemnye_web_programmy

Comment: как может быть `sis` равно `1`, сами то поняли, что написали?

Comment: @And- Я пытаюсь искать `echo "sistems"` где `case` это `"1" :` а `sis` это `$sistems` в `switch`. В чём я ошибся...?

Comment: В том, что вы не читали документацию по `switch`. В этом ошибка.

Comment: @And- вы правы , бегла пробежался по документации по `switch`. При этом `switch $_GET[link] case 'page' include (mysite.php)` у меня работает...

Comment: `switch` это условная конструкция, похожая на `if`, передача переменной в прототип и последующей проверки в `case`, в вашем случае вы передаете строку `sis` и сравниваете с `1`. если вы напишите за место `1` - `sis`, тогда заработает.

Comment: @And- вывести как `?sis=sis/..... `? Это у меня не сработало...

Comment: Вы вообще не понимаете, что делаете? разве `sis` равно `sis/.....` ? нет, нет и еще раз нет! Подумайте логически, у вас есть `1` рубль, а у меня `21`, разве у нас одинаковое количество? Верно! Нет! Так с какого ради `sis/.....` будет равно `sis` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если переменной присвоено значение "sis" - строковое значение, то передав эту переменную в switch для проверки вы в проверке case должны сравнивать значение именно с тем, какое у вас есть, иначе, код не будет выполняться.

```
$sistems = "sis";

switch ($sistems) {
  case "sis":
    echo "sistems";
    break;
}
```